# Copy a range from sheet 1 and insert only rows that are not blank in an existing table in sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

This is my sheet 1 (source data);

[sheet 1 = source (ws1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6yy.jpg)

I need to "copy" only the rows, where entire rows in the range A7:C1009 are not blank. This selection should then be entered in my sheet 2 (destination) starting from A7 in the table;

[sheet 2 = destination (ws2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlo2p.jpg)

I have managed to get this VBA working, but it will include all rows (menaing also the rows, where A:C are all blank/empty;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cl1 As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Indkøb") 'Indkøb
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Kalkulation3") 'Kalkulation3

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("a7:a1009")
    Set rng2 = ws1.Range("b7:b1009")
    Set rng3 = ws1.Range("c7:c1009")

    For Each cl1 In rng1
        r = cl1.Row
        c = cl1.Column

        If cl1.Value <> ws2.Cells(r, c).Value Then
            ws2.Cells(r, c).EntireRow.Insert
            ws2.Cells(r, c).Value = cl1.Value
        End If
    Next cl1
    For Each cl1 In rng2
        r = cl1.Row
        c = cl1.Column

        If cl1.Value <> ws2.Cells(r, c).Value Then
            ws2.Cells(r, c).Value = cl1.Value
        End If
    Next cl1
    For Each cl1 In rng3
        r = cl1.Row
        c = cl1.Column

        If cl1.Value <> ws2.Cells(r, c).Value Then
            ws2.Cells(r, c).Value = cl1.Value
        End If
    Next cl1

End Sub
```

This is what I want to accomplish;

1. Only rows where A:C are not empty should be copied from sheet 1 and inserted in the table in sheet 2.
2. If more rows are added in sheet 1, running the macro again should insert the rows in the table in sheet 2 and move the existing rows - ie. if I insert rows 20 and 21 in sheet 1, row 21 should be copied and inserted as the "new" 8th row in the table in sheet 2, moving all other values/formulas below 8th row 1 down.

Any input on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :-)

Comment: Will column A always have data in the rows you want to copy?

Comment: Yes - A and C will be filled (B is blank).

Comment: Anyone have an idea on how to get this working?

I have tried to modify my first 'for each' in rng1, but I cannot get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what you want for your #1 request. You will need a different macro to accomplish your #2 request. Sorry, I can't help you with that.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 7 To lRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A7")
```